# Second meanings of the colors (Verschiedene Bedeutung der Farben auf Deutsch)

Tags: meaning, adjective, slang

In verschiedenen Sprachen kann man den Farben eine zweite Bedeutung geben. Meiner Meinung nach hängt dieser angebliche Zuzammenhang von der Sprache ab. Was bedeuten die Farben auf Deutsch? Kann man Farben nutzen um Adjektive oder komplizierte Sachen zu beschreiben? Wenn möglich, erwähnen Sie bitte den Grund dieses Zusammenhangs und geben Sie ein Beispiel.

It is sometimes the case that one attributes a second meaning to the colors, in poetry or just slang. It might be that this association is language-dependent. 
What are the most common meanings attributed to colors in German? Provide, if possible, examples.

Comment: @all Ich würde es begrüßen, wenn wir auf diese Frage jetzt nicht 10 verschiedene Antworten erhalten, die alle noch eine weitere Farbenbedeutung hinzufügen. Eine Antwort, die alle Bedeutungen enthält, ist top. Kommentarfunktion ;) - Ist diese Frage nicht sogar vielleicht community wiki?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Germany, colors are commonly used for political parties/affiliations:

- green - the Green Party
- black - Christian Democratic Union ( black originally indicates Catholic, due to the color of priest's clothes)
- red - socialists/communists
- yellow - liberals
- brown - Nazis

In addition, colors are also associated with emotion, e.g.

- rot vor Wut
- schwarz (oder gruen oder gelb) vor Neid
- sich gruen und blau aergern

There are additional expressions derived from colors suggested by @userUnknown and @Em1, such as

- blau machen - taking time off (including skipping school)
- blau sein - being drunk (not being blue, i.e. feeling the blues!)
- grüne Gentechnik - genetic engineering of plants, as opposed to animals (note that there is a lot of opposition against it from the Green party)
- Schwarzarbeit/Schwarzbrennen/Schwarzfahren - working, distilling, or using public transport illegally.

Comment: grün ist die Hoffnung, rot die Liebe und Leidenschaft, blau ist kalt, orange ist Kraft, weiß die Unschuld und Sauberkeit, blau ist besoffen und doch auch treu, und schwarz ist der Tod, gelb und grün sind neid...

Comment: Zum Thema "politische Farben": [Ein schwarzer Politiker ist blau...](http://false-friends.crellin.de/2012/10/ein-schwarzer-politiker-ist-blau.html)

Comment: `Blau machen` ist auch Schwänzen, `Grün` steht auch für ökologisch (grünes Bauen), in `grüne Gentechnik` jedoch für `Gentechnik, die Pflanzen betreffend` wird es jedoch gerade von grünen Initiativen und den Grünen eher abgelehnt. Etwas `schwarz` machen (Schwarzarbeit, Schwarzbrennen, Schwarzfahren) meint immer verdeckt/heimlich. Ich meine aber, dass in allen Fällen, dies keine andere Bedeutung der Worte ist, sondern es ist immer von der Farbe abgeleitet.

Comment: weißer Terror := faschistischer Terror, rote Teufel := 1.FCK/Belgien, gelbe Pest := Symantec Antivirus, weiße Weihnacht := verschneites Väterchen-Frost-Fest... - der Sinn der Frage schwindet spätestens bei "grüne Bohnen".