# Haben "blau machen" und "blau sein" eine gemeinsame Etymologie?

Tags: etymology, proverb

Wie bereits [hier besprochen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/second-meanings-of-the-colors-verschiedene-bedeutung-der-farben-auf-deutsch) hat die Farbe Blau im Deutschen unter anderem noch folgende zusätzliche Bedeutungen:

- [**blau machen**](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blauer_Montag#Blau_machen): *sich einen freien Arbeitstag erschleichen*
- [**blau sein**](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blau#Alkohol): *alkoholisiert, betrunken sein*

Geht die Verwendung der Farbe Blau in diesen Wendungen auf eine gemeinsame sprachliche Wurzel zurück? Besteht vielleicht auch eine Beziehung zum englischen *"[Blues](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blues)"*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nach einiger Recherche, vor allem in dem wundervollen Buch *"[Zur Etymologie lexikalisierter Farbwortverbindungen](http://books.google.de/books?id=4FtclaWzNfkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=inauthor:%22Christiane%20Wanzeck%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zuUlUf3rA8il4ASgroCYAg&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA)"* von C. Wanzeck bin ich auf folgende Zusammenhänge gestoßen, die belegen, dass außer der Farbe keine weiteren Gemeinsamkeiten bestehen:

#### blau sein:

Dies geht offenbar auf eine ursprüngliche Bedeutung von *"blau"* im Sinne von dunkel, unheimlich, verschwommen zurück. Noch heute finden sich Wendungen, in denen dies zum Ausdruck kommt (z.B. *"einen blauen Dunst vormachen"*). Daraus wurde früher auch die Wendung *"es wird mir [blau vor Augen](http://books.google.de/books?id=4FtclaWzNfkC&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=%22blau%20vor%20den%20Augen%22&source=bl&ots=QE6V-qIiea&sig=1DOzZd5YC4xrBh2KKONsMG_XNQ4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qt0lUZGGOYXTswac4YGoDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22blau%20vor%20den%20Augen%22&f=false)"* (heute *"schwarz"*) für das Gefühl von Schwindel gebildet; erst viel später kam in der selben Bedeutung die Wendung *"blau sein"* für betrunken hinzu.

#### blau machen:

Usprünglich wurde der Fastnachtsmontag als arbeitsfreier Tag auch *"blauer Montag"* genannt, weil die Kirchen mit blauen Tüchern festlich geschmückt wurden. Daraus soll sich auch der *"blaue Montag"* für einen arbeitsfreien Tag von Handwerksgesellen herleiten, die diesen als Ausgleich für Sonntagsarbeit erhielten. Diese Bedeutung wird heute in der Wendung *"blau machen"* um einen (meist erschlichenen) freien Arbeitstag erweitert.

#### Blues:

Über den Ursprung von *"Blues"* ist weniger bekannt, jedoch gibt es Hinweise, dass die Verwendung von *"blue"* als Ausdruck einer traurigen Gemütslage schon vor Begründung der Musikrichtung verwendet wurde.<sup>[Marc Winter: Schweizer Bluesportal](http://www.bluesnews.ch/index2.php?option=com_content&do_pdf=1&id=283)</sup>
In diesem Zusammenhang ist interessant, dass schon im Mittelalter [Blau auch die Farbe der Trauer](http://books.google.de/books?id=4FtclaWzNfkC&lpg=PA145&ots=QE6V-qIiea&dq=%22blau%20vor%20den%20Augen%22&pg=PA133#v=snippet&q=%22Blau%20war%20im%20Mittelalter%20auch%20eine%20Trauerfarbe%22&f=false) war.

---

Weitere Referenzen:

- [Wissen.de: Keinen blauen Dunst, was "blaumachen" bedeutet?](http://www.wissen.de/keinen-blauen-dunst-was-blaumachen-bedeutet)
- [DWDS: blau](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=blau&view=1)
- [Grimm's Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?lemid=GB08002)
- [Rheinisches Conversations-Lexicon: Blauer Montag](http://books.google.de/books?id=CP80AAAAMAAJ&lpg=PA675&ots=O_RDnEg-uC&dq=%22Handwerksgesellen%20nicht%20arbeiten%22&pg=PA675#v=onepage&q=Blauer%20Montag&f=false)

Answer (score 11):

### Geschichte

Früher hat man mit der Pflanze [Färberwaid](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A4rberwaid) Dinge blau gefärbt. Dazu musste man die Blätter in Wasser legen und gären lassen. Dann hat man die Blätter ausgesiebt. Nun musste man Hydrosulfit in das Wasser geben und die blaue Farbe zum färben benutzt.

### Bedeutung

**blau sein**: Die Arbeiter haben etwas von der Farbe abbekommen. Sie mussten, ähnlich wie bei der Weinherstellung, in dem Topf rumstampfen. Sie wurden also *blau*.

Früher hat man hier viel Urin benötigt, vemutlich ist darin Hydrosulfit. Damit die an so viel Urin gekommen sind, haben sie viel Bier getrunken. Sie waren also betrunken.

**blau machen**: Die Arbeiter haben am Tag nach dem Färben frei bekommen, da dann der Stoff erstmal trocknen musste. Es gab also am nächsten Tag, *nach dem blau machen*, keine Arbeit mehr. Sie hatten also frei, weil sie blau gemacht haben.

### Antwort

Ja, „blau machen“ und „blau sein“ haben eine gemeinsame Etymologie.

### Quelle

Sendung mit der Maus  (z.B. auf YouTube [Teil 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eV99vhMgsc8), [Teil 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEpCFigdF8M))

Comment: +1 für die Maus als Quelle :)

Answer (score 2):

Nein. Die Herkunft der Redewendung "Blau sein" ist meist als der Zustand des Betrunken seins bekannt, da man bei zu starkem Alkoholgenuss an Sauerstoffmangel leidet und das Gesicht dadurch blau anläuft.

Wo auch immer "blau machen" wirklich herkommt (es ist ja immer noch diskutiert) - ich denke immer noch, dass es wirklich aus dem Färberwesen kommt (siehe den oben referenzierten Wikipediabeitrag). Damit wäre keinerlei Verbindung zu erkennen.

Das Wort *Blues* kommt aus dem Englischem *to feel blue*, da Blau oftmals mit Melancholie in Verbindung gebracht wird.

Comment: Ich habe auch schon eine Herkunftserklärung für `blau sein` gehört, welche sagt, dass früher zum blau gerben von Leder Urin benutzt wurde, wozu die Handwerker viel Bier trinken mussten.
Leider habe ich keine Quellen, welche dies belegen...

Comment: @Lukas: Das meine ich, mit dem Bezug auf das Färberwesen ;). Allerdings durften sich die Handwerker ja nicht blau trinken, sonst könnten sie das Leder ja nicht mehr *blau* machen :D.

Answer (score 1):

„Blau machen“ kommt von der Herstellung des blauen Farbstoffes aus Färberwaid (siehe oben genannte Quellen). Die dazu notwendigen Urinmengen wurden aber nicht von den Arbeitern der Waidspeicher gewonnen, sondern von Schenken (menschlicher Urin nach übermäßigem Biergenuss) und Pferdeställen (Pferdeurin). In Erfurt, der Hauptstadt der Färberwaidherstellung, sind überproportional viele damalige Schenken (auch Biereigenhäuser genannt) an Waidspeicher gebunden gewesen. Das ist selbst im heutigen Stadtbild noch erkennbar (Biereigenhäuser haben runde Löcher am Portal; Waidspeicher haben hohe Giebeldächer mit sehr vielen Fenstern).

Es gibt also keine standhafte Erklärung für die Redewendung „blau sein“, die auf der Gewinnung des blauen Farbstoffs aus Färberwaid beruht.

Answer (score 1):

According to the link below,
"blau" in "blau machen" derives from hebrew "be-lo" which means "without".

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_deutscher_W%C3%B6rter_aus_dem_Hebr%C3%A4ischen

Comment: And what is the connection of "without" to "blau machen"? Details might be found by Wikipedia, but the main argument should be shown here.

Answer (score -1):

Der hier gesuchte Zusammenhang beschränkt sich der Frage nach, wenn ich diese meinem Gefühl nach richtig deute, darauf, ob Montag blau gemacht wird, weil einer noch blau vom Wochenende ist.

Nein, sicher nicht.

Darüber hinaus ist die Frage schon weiter erörtert worden -- relativ sinnlos, angesichts der Ausgangslage.

Dem ließe sich noch hinzufügen, dass *blau sein* eventuell gar nichts mit der Farbe zu tun hätte. Zumindest kann festgestellt werden, dass *blau* früher nicht speziell die Farbe meinte, die wir heute darunter verstehen, sondern verschiedentlich Blässe bis strahlend leuchtende Farbe allgemein und sicherlich noch mehr (Kroonen vergleicht Lat. *flavus* "yellow"). Demnach könnte *blau* hier jeweils -- im Folgenden eher noch bei *blau sein* -- aus der Wurzel abgeleitet worden sein, bevor überhaupt ein engerer Bezug zu Farbe bestand, etwa in *blöde*, Eng. *blunt*; gesoffen wird ja quasi schon immer. Vergleich etwa *plümerant* oder auch *flau* (Das sollte dann zumindest nachweisbar sein; ist mangels Quellenlage dennoch schwierig). Vergleich eventuell *Schwindel*, *schwinden*, aus PIE *swey- "to hiss" [en.wiktionary], *bhleH- "to blow", auch "to cry" [en.wiktionary] (vgl. *blähen*; verlingt zu *blau*; *bh- führt allerdings mehrer ähnlicher Wurzeln an, *flavus* verlinkt wiederum, was sicherlich besser auf die Farben passt: *bhel- "shine"; sowie dort eben auch *blau* durch Proto-Germanisch *blewaz; Zusammenhang nicht abschließend geklärt; vgl. ferner *breath*, *breeze*)--vgl. "Frühling lässt sein blaues Band ..." [Fontane]; analog dazu siehe *flüchtig*, *plewk-, *plew-, welches etwa daraus abgeleitet werden kann, wenn ein s-Prefix typischerweise stimmlos macht, also *bh- zu *sp-, und das s dann etwa noch als Prefix erkenbar gewesen wieder entfernt. Das hab ich mir zwar erst ausgedacht -- also die Ableitung, nicht das s-Prefix, das als s-mobile bekannt noch als kaum verstanden gilt. Für *(s)p-l-(?) kenne ich ohnehin keinen passenden Vergleich; Vergleiche vielleicht *spülen* vs. *pleo* "flow". So! Spule, spülen, Spilunke, Spiel, Splitter, spell, splatter, spritzer, spei-übel ...

Ach, das ist alles graue(!) Theorie. Ausschließen, dass es sich bei *blau machen* und *blau sein* um echte Homonyme handelt, kann ich letztendlich doch nicht. Dazu ist die Beweiskette zu dünn, ohne roten Faden.

Dabei muss man sich mal fragen, ab wann bei verschmolzenen, ersteinerten Fügungen von gemeinsamen Wurzeln zu reden ist, wenn sich die Fügung durch synchronisches Verständnis verstärkt, selbst wenn dann von Volksglauben zu reden ist (d.h. *folk-etymology*, eigentlich *völkisch*, naja).

More research is needed.

PS: Zurück zu Fontane, da lag mir zwar das Augenmerk auf *blau*, vergleich aber auch *Frühling*, Eng. *spring*, sowie *Frühstück* zu *breakfast*, im Sinne der vorigen Ausführung. Ja auch Ger. *springen* zu *fliehen, fliegen*, vgl. Eng. *sparrow*, *swallow*--Das geht jetzt zwar entschieden zu weit ...