# Bedeutung der blauen Farbe in der deutschen Sprache

Tags: meaning

Welche Bedeutung hat die blaue Farbe in der deutschen Sprache und wofür steht sie? Ich kenne ziemlich viele Redewendungen, die irgendwas mit dieser Farbe zu tun haben: "blau machen", "eine Fahrt ins Blaue", "blau sein" usw. Und deswegen wundere ich mich, was sie für das Volk bedeutet.

Comment: related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6172/haben-blau-machen-und-blau-sein-eine-gemeinsame-etymologie

Comment: Ach so, das​ stand nicht bei "related questions". Danke

Comment: Definiere "das Volk"...

Comment: @Robert: Hier ist [eine Definition](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wir_sind_das_Volk) :-)

Comment: Wie Du gemerkt haben dürftest bedeutet sie je nach Kontext etwas anderes. Das ändert sich auch nicht durch Zugehörigkeit zum Volk oder Nichtzugehörigkeit.

Comment: @Robert Jedes Volk hat verschiedene Sitten und Gepflogenheiten und daher symbolisieren die verschiedene Farben verschiedene Sachen, was sich natürlich auch in der Sprache niederschlägt. Deswegen habe ich gefragt, welche Rolle der blauen Farbe aus Sicht der deutschen Kultur zukommt.

Comment: @VollDerChecker.  - Du bewegst dich auf glitschigem Gelände. Im deutschsprachigen Raum (aber eigentlich weltweit im Kreise von Ethnologen, Anthropologen, Soziologen, Politologen und Historikern) ist man mit Begriffen wie *das Volk* sehr vorsichtig geworden. Wer ernstgenommen werden will, kann solche Begriffe nicht unreflektiert benützen. Sie reflektiert zu benützen, heißt, sich zu überlegen, was ein Begriff wie *das Volk* bezeichnet, und ob es eine solche Entität in der realen Welt (außerhalb unserer Vorstellung) gibt, und wie ein solcher Begriff von wem wozu instrumentalisiert wird.

Comment: PS: Statt *... was sie für das Volk bedeutet* könntest sagen: *... was sie im alltäglichen Sprachgebrauch bedeutet*.